# echo five times a input with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How is repeated code HTML for five times?

like repeated(`echo`) a input `<input type="text" name="ok">` with a js code five times.

I mean this is that, a input by a js code echo five times

I want after run jQuery code output is this (5 input):

```
<input type="text" name="ok"> 
<input type="text" name="ok">
<input type="text" name="ok"> 
<input type="text" name="ok"> 
<input type="text" name="ok">
```

how is it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question isn't totally clear, do you mean this?

```
for (var i = 0; i<5;i++) {
    $("body").append("<input type='text' name='ok'>");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function EchoInput(html, count) {
    var result = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) 
        result.push(html);
    return result.join("");
}
```

To use this function, you could do something like this:

```
document.write(EchoInput("<input type='text' name='ok'>", 5));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var body = $('body');    

for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    body.append('<input type="text" name="ok">');
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ucbsh/1/

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating HTML, you can create elements directly.

Here is a way that let you set different names on each input field. Right now all five have the name "ok", but you can change that in the array:

```
// use ready event so that the page is loaded:
$(document).ready(function(){
  // decide where to add the elements:
  var container = $('body');
  // loop over an array of names:
  $.each(['ok','ok','ok','ok','ok'], function(idx, name) {
    // create an element and add to the container:
    container.append($('<input/>', { type: "text", name: name }));
  });
});
```